# scraping pagination web with beautifulsoup python

Tags: python, web, pagination, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

just started learning python. I'm trying to scrape all phone number from a paginated web site. but my code not go to paginate link and only looping on a same page. need advice here.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

for i in range(5000):
    url = "http://www.mobil123.com/mobil?type=used&page_number=1".format(i)
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

    for record in soup.findAll('div', {"class": "card-contact-wrap"}):
        for data in soup.findAll('div', {"data-get-content": "#whatsapp"}):
            print(record.find('li').text)
            print(data.text)
```

Comment: Should be `&page_number={}`, not `&page_number=1`, to have a formatted string.

Answer (score 1):

You missed placing string formatter. Change url = "...." to

```
  url = "http://www.mobil123.com/mobil?type=used&page_number={0}".format(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out you are missing the actual format placeholder, if you want all the pages you can scrape the number of pages from the initial page and loop in that range instead of trying to hard code the number of pages, it is on the second last li:

```
import requests

def get_pages(url):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content,"lxml")
    yield soup
    url += "{}"
    for n in range(2, int(soup.select("#js-listings-pagination li")[-2].text) + 1):
        yield BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url.format(n)).content)




start = "http://www.mobil123.com/mobil?type=used"

for soup in get_pages(start):
    print(soup)
```

Comment: Do i need to use lxml? get an error when try to install lxml "error unable to find vcvarsall.bat

Comment: Nope,  just a habit. You can use the default parser